# How can i display markers from a database?

Tags: openlayers-2, markers

I'm an absolute GIS beginner and here is what i am trying to achieve.
I am developing a web application that allows users to :

1. type an address, and be displayed the corresponding slipping map
2. select a point on this map, and create a marker with custom info
3. this marker and associated info will be stored in a database
4. every user requesting an address will be presented a slipping map,
   showing all the markers other users have defined.

So far, i have learnt how to get lat/lon from an address, using nominatim, and display a map via openlayers. I think i know how to store markers in a database, but i don't have a clue how to display an openlayers slipping map, with my markers (several thousands) applied on it ?
Is it possible without installing my own mapserver/geoserver ?
Thanks for your hints.

Christine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i found [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html) how to display my markers from a kml file. And generating my kml file from a database shouldn't be too hard.